# "kubectl get" vs "kubectl logs" -- different behaviours

Tags: kubernetes

From my workstation I can list pods, check component status etc.

```
[dude@bionic K8s]$ kubectl get componentstatuses
NAME                 STATUS    MESSAGE             ERROR
controller-manager   Healthy   ok
scheduler            Healthy   ok
etcd-2               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-0               Healthy   {"health":"true"}
etcd-1               Healthy   {"health":"true"}

[dude@bionic K8s]$ kubectl get svc -A
NAMESPACE     NAME         TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.32.0.1    <none>        443/TCP                  41d
kube-system   kube-dns     ClusterIP   10.32.0.10   <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   49m

[dude@bionic K8s]$ kubectl get pod -n kube-system coredns-574fc576d6-4hbl4
NAME                       READY   STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
coredns-574fc576d6-4hbl4   0/1     CrashLoopBackOff   13         46m
```

But when I want to view logs (to debug the CrashLoop above), I get a certificate error:

```
[dude@bionic K8s]$ kubectl logs -n kube-system coredns-574fc576d6-4hbl4
plugin/kubernetes: Get "https://10.32.0.1:443/version?timeout=32s": x509: certificate is valid for 172.16.68.221, 172.16.68.222, 172.16.68.223, 172.16.68.69, 127.0.0.1, not 10.32.0.1
```

Why is this?  My setup is a haproxy in front of three control nodes.  The haproxy is on 172.16.68.69, which is configured in my kubeconfig:

```
apiVersion: v1
clusters:
- cluster:
    server: https://172.16.68.69:6443
```

It's like for some reason 'kubectl logs' decides to discover the ClusterIP somehow and use that directly, while other kubectl commands use the properly configured server.

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. The problem was that I had not included 10.32.0.1 in the kubernetes.pem cert.  I hadn't though I needed to do this but I did, presumably as connections initiated by the apiserver don't go through the haproxy, only inbound connections do.

I recreated kubernetes.pem and kubernetes-key.pem including the cluster IP as a kubernetes hostname, then distributed these certs to /etc/etcd and /var/lib/kubernetes on the controllers and restarted kube-apiserver.  All good now :)

(this also solved the crashloop issue too)